# proof verification $f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

let $X$ be compact $f $ continuous and $A\subseteq X$ prove that $f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$

solution:

take $f(x) \in f(\overline{A})\Rightarrow x \in \overline{A}\Rightarrow$

$\exists \: x_n\subseteq A : x_n\rightarrow x$ now since $x_n\subseteq A$ and
$f$ is cont. $f(x_n)\subseteq f(A)$ and $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)\Rightarrow$

$f(x) \in  \overline{f(A)}$

Comment: If $f$ is indeed continuous it is correct but I would rather write $(x_n)$ to note the sequence and define $y_n = f(x_n)$ so the reasonning is more explicit but that last point is nitpicking

Comment: $f$ is  continuous i just forgot to write it.

Comment: Hey, we asked the same question around the same time. Check out my proof, I used a different approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953762/proving-set-inclusion-for-a-continuous-map-f

Comment: You can drop the compactness assumption and the claim still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your reasoning is correct, but you need to connect the ideas in a better way. Here is a better way to prove it*

Let $x \in f(\bar{A}),$ thus there exists $x_{0} \in \bar{A}$ such that $f\left(x_{0}\right)=x .$ Thus, we have that $x_{n} \in A$ with $x_{n} \rightarrow x_{0} .$ since $f$ is continuous, it follows that $\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} f\left(x_{n}\right)=f\left(\lim _{n \rightarrow+\infty} x_{n}\right)=f\left(x_{0}\right)=x .$ Therefore, since $f\left(x_{n}\right) \in f(A), \forall n$
and $f\left(x_{n}\right) \longrightarrow x,$ then $x \in \overline{f(A)} .$ We conclude that :
$$f(\bar{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$$

Comment: Yes, you are right, and i do this more often than i should, i will try to fix it and be more formalist thanks for writing down the proof.

Comment: It is normal at first to write down proofs while skipping some steps but the more you practice the more your proofs will be strong and rigorous.